# Youtube in Safari cause system crash

Tags: macbook-pro, safari, crash, youtube, reboot

Regarding [MacBook Pro early 2011: sound loop, black screen](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/148868/macbook-pro-early-2011-sound-loop-black-screen)

It happened again and it's the 5th time in one month. Everytime I play **youtube videos on Safari only** the screen just freeze and the fan gets much louder.

I forced it to shut down and when I turn it on again I got black/grey/blue screens..

Is the Flash Player the main source of problem here? I updated it to the latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing I would always try for Flash issues is to disable Hardware Acceleration...

Right click any Flash video & select `Settings...`

[image: Flash Settings]

Then click the first tab at the bottom & uncheck `Enable hardware acceleration`

[image: Hardware Acceleration]

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will do that once my school break is about to end; I need a stabile computer to finish my work :)